# Video.js on multiple videos in a list

Tags: magento, video.js

Im trying to use video.js on a product list in magento to show trailers of the product.
Im abel to get it to work with the first video in the list but the others starts playing in the popup but i cant close them , i can close the first one but not the others .

The video.js im using is video.min.js - HTML5 Video Player Version 3.1.0

Here is my code for calling the video function

```
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <li class="item">
            <div class="item-list" >
            <?php // Product Image ?>
                <div class="product-shop">
                    <?php $format = Icommerce_Default::getOptionValue( $_product, 'produkt_variant' );?>

                        <div class="format-list">
                            <?php if($format): ?>
                                <?php $path = "/media/format-list/".Icommerce_Default::urlify($format).".png"; ?>
                                    <?php if( Icommerce_Default::siteFileExists($path) ): ?>
                                        <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseURL() . $path; ?>" alt="<?php echo $format; ?>" width="35" height="15" />
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>


                <div class="list-titel" style="display:inline;"><a class="imgTip" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName())?><span><div class="prev-img"><img class="tTip" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(110, 153); ?>" width="110" height="153" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" /></div></span></a></div>
                    <?php $release = $_product->getFilmReleasedatum() ?>

                    <div class="releasedatum-list" style="display:inline;"><?php echo date("Y-m-d" , strtotime($release));?></div>
                    <div class="list-price"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice()); ?></div>
                    <div class="rea-buttom">
                        <?php
                        // Get the Special Price
                        $specialprice = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSpecialPrice();
                        // Get the Special Price FROM date
                        $specialPriceFromDate = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSpecialFromDate();
                        // Get the Special Price TO date
                        $specialPriceToDate = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSpecialToDate();
                        // Get Current date
                        $today =  time();

                        if ($specialprice):
                            if($today >= strtotime( $specialPriceFromDate) && $today <= strtotime($specialPriceToDate) || $today >= strtotime( $specialPriceFromDate) && is_null($specialPriceToDate)):
                                ?>
                                <img src="/skin/frontend/pro/ic_hemma/images/rea.png" width="20" height="20" />
                            <?php
                            endif;
                        endif;
                        ?>


                    </div>         
           <?php $filmUrl = $_product->getFilmUrl(); ?>
                <?php if ($filmUrl): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $filmUrl; ?>" class="trailer-trigger" rel="#prompt<?php echo $k ?>" >Film</a>

                        <div class="trailer" id="prompt<?php echo $k ?>">
                            <video id="trailer" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" preload="auto" width="640" height="360" data-setup='{"controls":true, "preload": "auto", "autoplay": true, "techOrder": ["flash","html5"]}'>
                                <source src="<?php echo $filmUrl; ?>" type="video/mp4" />
                            </video>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

[video.js file can be looked at here](http://www.imonline.se/demo/video)

Comment: Have you written any script for handling close functionality ? Please specify js used for puase functionality

Comment: Ill only use the vidoe.js for controlls i have attached it to the prev post you can look at it there